# Highcharts MTD (Month to Date) and QTD (Quater to Date) implementation

Tags: highcharts

does anyone done the MTD and QTD implementation in Highcharts ?
Below is the MTD implementation, after done the calculation will pass to the range selector.

```
var currentDate = new Date("March 05, 2013 00:00:00");
var tempDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime());
tempDate.setDate(1);
mtdCount = parseInt((currentDate.getTime() - tempDate.getTime())/(24 * 3600 * 1000));

options = {

chart: {
renderTo: 'container',
zoomType: 'xy'
}

rangeSelector: {
selected: 1,

buttons: [{
type: 'day',
count: mtdCount,
text: 'MTD'
}, {
type: 'all',
text: 'All'
}]
}

};

Highcharts.setOptions({
global: {
useUTC: false
}
});
```

However, the result is invalid, such as the current date is 05 march 2013.
Thus suppose the date range of this current date in MTD is start from 01 march 2013 to 05 march 2013, but it end up with 28 february 2013 to 05 march 2013.

I'm unsure where the root problem is ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your timezone? You have to convert the time for all your data to UTC+0:00 by doing offset.

Comment: Hello You Qi, the time for all my data is shown as below format Tue Mar 05 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)

Comment: as I said, offset all your time in your series by subtracting 8hours. 28800 seconds.

Comment: Hi, my data date range is start from 01/11/2010 to 05/03/2013. If I had offset the time, then the date range will be 31/10/2010 to 04/03/2013. Sorry You Qi, if i misunderstand your suggestion.

Comment: Take this example: `unixtime: 1363665136`, which is `2013-03-19 11:52:16AM MYT`. But if you plot it in highcharts, it will become `3:52 am`. It's a known issue with highcharts. To show `11:52am` correctly, you have to add 8hours to your time. `1363665136+28800=1363693936`

Comment: Hi You Qi, Im have attached the solution file for you have a clearer visual. thank you.

http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1363668517

Comment: ok. I now understand your problem. The root cause is highstock needs a minimum of 5 points to render a chart. your data is just too small and therefore it added october data to the drawing

Comment: oic, thank you You Qi. looks like you quite familiar with Highcharts JS

Comment: @YouQi data x should be timestamp in Javascript format and sorted by x, ascending

Comment: @You Qi Hello, you qi. do you have the same experienced as me for this post ? thank you.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740909/add-flag-based-on-button-event)