# Add Flag based on button event

Tags: highcharts

```
series: [{

type: 'flags',
name: 'Flags on axis',

data: [{
x: Date.UTC(2011, 2, 1),
title: 'A'

}, {
x: Date.UTC(2011, 5, 1),
title: 'C'
}],

shape: 'squarepin'
}]

 $("#btnAddFlag").click(function () {

chart.series[0].setData(
{

x: Date.UTC(2011, 2, 1),
title: 'B'
});

});
```

Above code is part of highstock chart option and I want to add flag based on user event click. However I able to add the new point flag into the chart but the existing flags which title A and C will be missed out.

1. how can I add the new flag into the chart with the existing flags ?
2. On the other hand, I am able get the flag data but I'm unsure to
   generate the correct data structure and reinitialize the old and new
   flag data back into the chart.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use addPoint instead of setData.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.addPoint()

```
$("#btnAddFlag").click(function () {
  chart.series[0].addPoint({
    x: Date.UTC(2011, 2, 1),
    title: 'B'
  });
});
```

Comment: Hello, but user able to keep click on the button, thus the flag icon will be duplicate on the same axis, thank you

Comment: After click you can disable button or modify x param